# Borrow inner data from struct in a wrapper function

Tags: rust

I've been working on making a library (`rust-websocket`) use more borrows and less owned data. This involved adding a `Cow` to a struct, which involved adding a lifetime to that struct, which made the **entire library** need lifetimes.

In short I have one problem left, and I've been trying to solve it for days. It can be summarized with this code:

```
{   // This works great!
    let mut sender = Wire;
    let message = Text("Hello World!".to_string());
    sender.send_message(&message);
}
{   // This DOES NOT COMPILE!
    let mut client = Client {
        sender: Wire,
        packet: PhantomData,
    };
    let message = Text("Hello World!".to_string());
    client.send(&message);
}
```

In the above example `client.send` is a wrapper around `sender.send_message`, both have the same definition. Although in the case of `client.send` the message being send must live *longer* than the client. In the `sender.send_message` case the message only has to live for the lifetime of the function call.

```
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::iter::{Take, Repeat, repeat};
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Sender<P> {
    fn send_packet(&mut self, packet: &P) -> Result<(), ()>;

    fn send_message<'m, M>(&mut self, message: &'m M) -> Result<(), ()>
        where M: Message<'m, P>,
              P: 'm
    {
        for ref packet in message.iter() {
            try!( self.send_packet(packet) );
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

trait Message<'p, P>
    where P: 'p
{
    type PacketIterator: Iterator<Item = P>;
    fn iter(&'p self) -> Self::PacketIterator;
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Packet<'d> {
    data: Cow<'d, [u8]>,
}

struct Text(String);

impl<'p> Message<'p, Packet<'p>> for Text {
    type PacketIterator = Take<Repeat<Packet<'p>>>;

    fn iter(&'p self) -> Take<Repeat<Packet<'p>>> {
        repeat(Packet {
            data: Cow::Borrowed(self.0.as_bytes()),
        }).take(1)
    }
}

struct Wire;

impl<'s> Sender<Packet<'s>> for Wire {
    fn send_packet<'p>(&mut self, packet: &Packet<'p>) -> Result<(), ()> {
        println!("Sent {:?}", packet);
        Ok(())
    }
}

struct Client<P, S> {
    sender: S,
    packet: PhantomData<P>
}

impl<P, S> Client<P, S>
    where S: Sender<P>
{
    fn send<'m, M>(&mut self, message: &'m M) -> Result<(), ()>
        where M: Message<'m, P>,
              P: 'm
    {
        self.sender.send_message(message)
    }
}

fn main() {
    {   // This works great!
        let mut sender = Wire;
        let message = Text("Hello World!".to_string());
        sender.send_message(&message);
    }
    {   // This DOES NOT COMPILE!
        let mut client = Client {
            sender: Wire,
            packet: PhantomData,
        };
        let message = Text("Hello World!".to_string());
        client.send(&message);
    }
}
```

I put the entire [code on the Rust Playground](http://is.gd/MiBBbG)

I wish I could better describe my problem so it can be better searched for, so I will change my title once I know what's going on.

Comment: You're definitely right, but that is the behavior I don't want, I should have been more clear. Because of the lifetime constraint you pointed out all messages would have to be made in advance before the client is ever created! I want these lifetimes (client & message) to be separate.

Comment: A bit off topic, but I'd highly encourage you to follow the Rust-standard formatting for where clauses. [Something like this](http://is.gd/h0A9ej). I'm having lots of trouble scanning your code to see how your generics are used. My more personal preference is to always use a where clause instead of inlining it like `<A, B: Foo<A>>`

Comment: I prefer `where` too (except for lifetimes). Good to know that there's a standard style, I'll be happy to follow it.

Comment: @Shepmaster changed the style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `PhantomData<P>` to `PhantomData<fn(P)>`. Your type doesn't store `P`, it operates on `P`.

The problem here is that you're claiming to *store* a `P` which means that the type `P` must outlive the type `Client<S, P>`. For `P` (the packet type) to outlive the `Client` type, `message` itself must outlive `client` because you're borrowing packets from messages. However, in this case, `client` outlives `message` because `client` is allocated first on the stack (and stacks are torn down in reverse order).